# Two different sized images one line bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I found many variations on this question, but I couldn't find the answer to mine specifically so here it is.

Boostrap 3

I have two images. The first is 307x404. The second is 1548 x 1161. I want to have both of them display responsively on one line (big image on the left, smaller one on the right).

Right now the two images display on two lines. My code is as of now:

`<div class="about" id="about">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="text-center" style="font-weight: bold;">About My Shop</h1>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                        <img class="img-responsive firstImage" src="img/first.png" alt="">
                        <img class="img-responsive secondImage" src="img/second.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>`

`.secondImage {
        display: block;
        margin-right: 30px;
        float: right;
    }
    .firstImage {
        display: block;
        float: left;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

try to use .secondImage , .firstImage { display:inline-block;max-width:50%} and remove the float from both.

Comment: Ty for suggestion! I tried that, but they still display on two lines. Also in terms of width, I was hoping to have the left image take up more width space (e.g. 60%) and have the right image (since its dimensions are thinner) take up less space (maybe 40% or less)

Comment: ok then you must place the first image in a div with  col-xs-8 col-md-8 class and second image in col-xs-4 col-md-4 div class

Comment: Thanks that worked. Now my images are smaller, but they are on one line which is what I asked. Thank you! **edit** I changed the wrapping div wrapping both the images from col-xs-12 col-md-6 to col-md-12